# MongoDB: Decrement all documents with field value higher then defined

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to decrement all documents with order greater then a given value and a given parent value:

```
var order = 5, parent = "books";
Articles.update({ parent: parent, order > order }, $inc { order: -1 }, {multi: true});
```

In this example all documents with parent = books and with a higher order value of 5 are updated to an decremented order value. I don't know if this is possible with one line or do I have to start the update() multiple times in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close already. Here's a [list of comparison operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/) for MongoDB

```
var order = 5,
    parent = 'books'

Articles.update(
    { parent : parent, order : { $gt : order } },
    { $inc : { order : -1 } },
    { multi : true }
)
```